# Devise with Omniauth for facebook authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, devise, omniauth

I am running ruby 1.9.2p18, Devise (1.3.4), Rails (3.0.4) and Omniauth (0.2.6).

Currently I have my webpage doing authentication with Devise, and it works fine.

I am trying to also add facebook authentication to it. I followed the instruction from https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3a-Overview .

When I do localhost:3000 I get

```
LoadError (no such file to load -- omniauth/core):
  app/models/user.rb:3:in `<class:User>'
  app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  config/routes.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
  config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

and if refresh the page again sometimes I get

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/")
```

I looked and under .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/omniauth-0.2.6 I have the directory oa-core/ but not core/ .

I would really appreciate the help, I have no idea how to debug this one!

Answer (score 1):

2 errors are different.

**1. Error:**

```
LoadError (no such file to load -- omniauth/core)
```

You need to add omniauth to your Gemfile and run 'bundle install'. If you've problem with it this Railscast might help:
[Railscasts Omniauth 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-omniauth-part-1)

Also see 2 Devise videos on Railscasts.

**2. Error:**

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/")
```

It says you haven't configured your app to have a main root. The main root is which matches "/".
- First choose which page you would like as landing page you or homepage. If you haven't created one then do it.
- Next you can find all named routes from shell by "rake routes".
- Then open config/routes.rb file and add main root by:

```
root :to => 'welcome#index'
```

**substitute "welcome#index" with "your_chosen_controllers_name#chosen_method"**
*Don't add a named route created by Devise because it will end up with infinite loop* ("stack level too deep" error).

Note that Devise wiki recommend no to use Devise if you've no prior experience with Rails. In this case I highly recommend to checkout Rails3.1 new has_secure_password? method.
HTH

Comment: @meena, did you get this solution. I am having same issue but could not get solution. Please let me know if you got solution for it.